# Tipar valor devuelto por funciones y metodos en PHP

Tags: php, symfony

Estoy desarrollando una pequeña aplicación con Symfony 4.4 + PHP 7.3.

Para tener algo mas de claridad en el código (vengo de realizar desarrollos en Java) estoy indicando el tipo de valores devueltos por los metodos de las clases.

Hasta aquí bien, el problema viene cuando tengo un metodo que devuelve un valor de tipo 'resource' concretamente de tipo 'gd' (es una imagen para un captcha).

Cuando indico que el valor que retorna el metodo es de tipo 'resource':

```
private function generarImagen() : \resource {
    ...
}
```

Obtengo la excepción:

*Return value of App\Utils\Captcha\CaptchaGenerator::generarImagen() must be an instance of resource, resource returned*

He probado indicando tambien \gd en lugar de resouce pero me indica lo mismo pero para 'gd':

*Return value of App\Utils\Captcha\CaptchaGenerator::generarImagen() must be an instance of gd, resource returned*

La función get_resource_type devuelve 'gd' y la funcion gettype devuelve 'resource'.

¿Alquilen sabe el por que de esto?

Answer (score 1):

**No existe type declaration** (antes conocido como type-hint) para el tipo `resource`. 
Los tipos que puedes declarar son:

- Previo a PHP 7:

  - nombre de clase o interfaz (ya sea usando FQCN o mediante `use` para importar el nombre)
  - self
  - array
  - callable
- En PHP 7.0 se añadió soporte para hintear/declarar escalares:

  - bool
  - float
  - int
  - string
- En PHP 7.1 se añadió soporte para  `iterable` (que es ya sea un `array` [o un objeto compatible con la interfaz Traversable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.iterable.php))
- En PHP 7.2 se añadió soporte para `object`. (por ejemplo la instancia de una clase [o el casteo de un array a un objeto](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting))

Aunque hay una corriente en la comunidad PHP para añadir type declaration a todo lo que se pueda, en varios aspectos es un arma de doble filo. Específicamente para el tipo [resource](https://www.php.net/manual/es/resource.php), el argumento en contra es que varias extensiones (que no se rigen por el mismo sistema de RFC de PHP) que solían trabajar con resources han ido migrando a trabajar con objetos, como es el caso de la extensión de precisión arbitraria [GMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-init.php), cuya función factoría devuelve:

> **Return Values**
>
> A GMP number [resource](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php) in PHP 5.5 and earlier, or a [GMP object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.gmp.php) in PHP 5.6 and later.

En otras palabras, decirle a tu función que debe retornar un resource es ponerse demasiado específico. En rigor, si se pudiera, debiera ser: "retorna lo que sea que retornan los métodos de GD, que hoy son resources pero mañana nadie sabe".

**Workaround**

Si usas una herramienta de análisis estático como [psalm](https://psalm.dev/) puedes lograr lo mismo que buscas con docblocks cuando corras un chequeo (por ejemplo en un pre-commit hook):

```
/**
 * Genera una imagen con GD
 *
 * @return \resource recurso de la imagen generada
 */
 private function generarImagen() {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: No estoy usando ninguna herramienta de análisis. Ante esta tesitura, si mi clase tiene varios métodos en los que indico que tipo de valor devuelven estos (escalares), que es lo mas correcto en ese caso?

Comment: Para cualquier tipo que indiqué más arriba definir el tipo es lo correcto. Si pudiera devolver más de un tipo ahí ya hay que usar docblocks

Answer (score 1):

En PHP (`7+`) `resource` no está reconocido como un [tipo de retorno válido](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types), porque no ha sido reconocido como un [tipo escalar](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints).

Pero la situación para este caso especifico se puede manejar de otro modo: verificando dentro del método si es un recurso con `is_resource`.

Por ejemplo:

```
private function generarImagen() {
    #código que obtiene la imagen..., imaginemos que se guarda en $img
    if ( is_resource ($img) ) {
        return $img;
    } else {
        return NULL; #O levantar una Exception o lo que quieras
    }
}
```

#### Para más detalles ver:

- [PHP 7 and strict “resource” types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38429595/5587982)
- [Nota de contribución en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.returning-values.php#120402)